# Tracking the point of intersection of a simulated time series with a specific value over many runs in OpenBUGS

Tags: winbugs

I have an OpenBUGS model that uses observed data (y.values) over time (x.values) to simulate many runs (~100000) with new estimates of y-values (y.est) for each run. The observed data exhibit a pronounced decline from a maximum value.

I want to keep track of the length of time it takes for each run to decline from the maximum abundance (T.max) to 10% of the maximum abundance (T.10%). Because the maximum abundance value changes from run to run, 10% of that maximum will also vary from run to run, and thus T.10% will vary from run to run.

Setting a parameter to store T.max is easy enough, that doesn't vary from run to run because the maximum value is sufficiently greater than any other value.

What I can't figure out, is how to store the intersection of the y-est values and T.10%.

My first attempt was to determine whether each y-est value is above or below T.10% using the `step()` function:

```
above.below[i] <- step(T.10% - y.est[i])
```

This generates a string of ones and zeros for each y.est value (e.g., 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, etc.) If each run simply declined continuously from a maximum to a minimum, I could use the `rank()` function to  determine how many `above.below[i]` values occur above T.10%:

```
decline.length <- rank(above.below[1:N], 0)
```

In this example, `decline.length` would be equal to the number of '0's in the string above, which is 9. Unfortunately, the y-est values occasionally display periods of growth following their decline below T.10%. So, the vector of `above.below` values can look like this: 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, etc. Thus, `decline.length` would equal 14 rather than 9, given the subsequent 0s in the vector.

What I want to do, is figure out how to store only the number of '0's in `above.below` prior to the first '1'; `above.below[1:10]` rather than `above.below[1:N]`. Unfortunately, it's not always the 10th time step in which the first '1' occurs, so I need to make the maximum extent of the range of `above.below` vary from run to run during the simulation.

I'm struggling to accomplish this in OpenBUGS since it's a non-procedural language, but I think it can be done, I just don't know the trick to do it. I'm hoping someone more familiar with the `step()` and `rank()` functions can lend some expert advice.

Any guidance is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two solutions offered to me:

1) Calculate the cumulative sum up to each time step:

```
for (i in 1:N){
    above.below[i] <- step(T.10% - y.est[i])
    cum.above.below[i] <- sum(above.below[1:i])
}

decline.length <- rank(cum.above.below[1:N], 0)
```

2) Calculate whether each year is above or below the threshold directly, without 1s and 0s:

```
for(i in 1:N){
    above.below[i] <- step(T.10% - y.est[i])
    dummy[i] <- above.below[i] * i + (1 - above.below[i]) * (N+1)
}

decline.length <- ranked(dummy[], 1)
```

So `dummy` is `i` when `above.below` is 1, and `dummy` is N+1 when `above.below` is 0.